# How to do a slow pulse circle on javascript within a function?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, geometry

I have drew some circle functions in javascript and would like to add a function of slow pulsing effect to it. Below is my js code, can anyone help me please?

Thanks!!!

Karen x

```
   function newCircle1 (x,y){

            var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.fillStyle="rgb(255,255,255,0.65)";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,10,0,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();         
    }

            function newCircle2 (x,y){

            var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.fillStyle="rgb(255,255,255)";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();
        }


        function getMousePos(canvas,evt){

        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return{

            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){
            var mousePos = getMousePos (canvas,evt);

            newCircle1(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
            newCircle2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);     

        }, false);
}
```

Comment: So you create a new context for every circle?

Comment: @Troy: afaik, there is only one 2d context per canvas. Repeatedly calling `canvas.getContext("2d")` won't create a new one, but return the same every time. But you're right, `ctx` should simply be on the same scope as `canvas`.

Comment: @Bergi and Troy: Yes, there is one-and-only-one context per canvas.  Multiple calls to canvas.getContext will get the same context each time ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example is based on markE's example. This has the radius and opacity oscillating between two min and max points. Adjust the settings to mess around with the drawing output:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/er4t1uec/)**

```
var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' ),
    ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' ),
    width = canvas.width = 300,
    height = canvas.height = 300,
    baseRadius = { min: 3, max: 18 },
    baseOpacity = { min: 0.3, max: 0.7 },
    mouse = { x: -9999, y: -9999 },
    tick = 0,
    osc1,
    osc2,
    bounds;

function onresize() {
  bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
}

function onmousemove( e ) {
  mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top;    
}

function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame( loop );
  osc1 = 0.5 + Math.sin( tick / 13 ) * 0.5;
  osc2 = 0.5 + Math.sin( tick / 19 ) * 0.5;

  var radius = baseRadius.min + ( ( baseRadius.max - baseRadius.min ) * osc1 ),
      opacity = baseOpacity.min + ( ( baseOpacity.max - baseOpacity.min ) * osc1 );

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc( mouse.x, mouse.y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 );
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + opacity + ')';
  ctx.fill();

  tick++;
}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onresize );
window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onmousemove );

document.body.appendChild( canvas );
onresize();
loop();
```

[image: GIF Animation]